# I want to use aggregate function in attribute having integer name in it

Tags: mysql, sql, database, aggregate-functions

I am using following mysql query in relation **review(70,60,30)** that is having attribute name with integer value

```
SELECT AVG(70) FROM `review`;
```

But problem is that I am getting 70.0000 as answer which is not a correct one as it recognize 70 as value not a attribute name..

Plz help...

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  `AVG()` does not work on "names" (at least "names" that are strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it with the table name too:

```
SELECT AVG(review.70) FROM `review`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `70` is the name of a column, I encourage you to change the name!

```
alter table review change column `70` `value_70` . . . ;
```

But, if you are stuck with it, use backticks:

```
SELECT AVG(`70`)
FROM review;
```